# React Native Camera Roll

Tags: react-native

Haven't noticed much sample code/guides on how to use the CameraRoll library from React Native, I found the example in the docs a bit "vague" and confusing.

First time I'm using any of the API's so I do not fully understand how I'm suppose to use the library either. So far I've imported it like:

```
    import {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  Navigator,
  CameraRoll,
  Alert,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Button,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
```

quite confused with "Linking" etc, but as far as I know, this should be all I need to do in order to use the lib.

And **how** do I use it for something as simple as to open the gallery on the click of a button and let the user choose an image that should then be displayed in the app.

Thanks in advance, hope someone has some code to clarify this.

Comment: I've used this feature before. Are you trying to add this to an iOS or Android project?

Comment: @13Leprechauns to both! I was hoping that React Native would take care of the cross-platform part?

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code that will grab the first 25 photos from your camera roll and display them in a `ScrollView`. I modified this from an example I found online [here](https://thebhwgroup.com/blog/accessing-iphone-camera-roll-images-react-native)

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import {
  CameraRoll,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

class CameraRollView extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    var controls = props.controls
    this.state = {
      images: [],
      selected: '',
      fetchParams: { first: 25 },
      groupTypes: 'SavedPhotos',
    }
    this._storeImages = this._storeImages.bind(this)
    this._logImageError = this._logImageError.bind(this)
    this._selectImage = this._selectImage.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // get photos from camera roll
    CameraRoll.getPhotos(this.state.fetchParams, this._storeImages, this._logImageError);
  }

  // callback which processes received images from camera roll and stores them in an array
  _storeImages(data) {
    const assets = data.edges;
    const images = assets.map( asset => asset.node.image );
    this.setState({
        images: images,
    });
  }

  _logImageError(err) {
      console.log(err);
  }

  _selectImage(uri) {
    // define whatever you want to happen when an image is selected here
    this.setState({
      selected: uri,
    });
    console.log('Selected image: ', uri);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.imageGrid}>
            { this.state.images.map(image => {
              return (
               <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this._selectImage(image.uri)}>
                 <Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: image.uri }} />
               </TouchableHighlight>
             );
            })}
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  imageGrid: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  image: {
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      margin: 10,
  },
});

export default CameraRollView
```

Comment: Is it possible to bring up the native gallery instead of having a custom scene displaying a set of images? I would imagine some function for bringing up the native gallery on both iOS and Android?

Comment: Do you know if I can get photos filtered by 'Selfies' Album?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, the package you are seeking is probably react-native-image-picker. It allows you to take a photo or select one from your native device gallery.

LINK: https://github.com/react-community/react-native-image-picker

In response to the linking issue. When you save a package using:

**npm install --save react-native-image-picker**

What is happening here is the **--save** part prepares the packages dependencies to be connected to native iOS and Android. This linking is done using the command **react-native link**.

In some cases packages require some manual linking aswell (for example, this package requires a small amount of native iOS and Android configuration)