# How can get recent images of device in the app itself same as it is in Facebook messenger app?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, react-native

I'm building a react native app and I have to add a option of getting the image in the app itself ,  select image and sending it to user. But i don't know to get the device recent images in the app itself. Anyone can help?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Camera Roll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941414/react-native-camera-roll)